# Can map coercions be set as delegates?

Tags: groovy, metaprogramming

I am building a simple psuedo-xml builder using Groovy's runtime metaprogramming facilities. I built a class that does this sucessfully, however when I tried a different approach by coercing a map into an interface, I ran into problems with the Groovy `methodMissing` apparatus.

Approaches I've tried are coercing a map with a `methodMissing` key containing a `Closure` into an interface with `methodMissing` defined and a `GroovyObject`

Here is main:

```
mybuilder = new builder() //good
mybuilder.xml = { ->
    thelettersofdaalpabet {
        "q"
    }
}

mycoercionbuilder = new coercionbuilder() //errors out
mycoercionbuilder.messages = { ->
    thelettersofdaalpabet {
        "q"
    }
}
```

builder(which works):

```
class builder {
    def methodMissing(String methodName, args){
        println "<$methodName>"
        for(Closure c : args){
            c.delegate = this
            def out = c()
            if (out != null) println out
        }
        println "</$methodName>"
    }

    def propertyMissing(String propName, val) {
        this.methodMissing(propName,val)
    }
}
```

and coercionbuilder(which errors out):

```
class coercionbuilder {
    def b = [
            methodMissing: { String methodName, args ->
                println "<$methodName>"
                for (Closure c : args) {
                    c.delegate = b
                    def out = c()
                    if (out != null) println out
                }
                println "</$methodName>"
            }] as builderrules //<-- I also changed this value to GroovyObject

    def propertyMissing(String propName, val) {
        this.b.methodMissing(propName, val)
    }
}
```

this is the builderrules interface mentioned in the coercionbuilder:

```
interface builderrules {
    def methodMissing(String methodName, args)
}
```

When the map is coerced into a builderrules it outputs:

```
<xml>
<thelettersofdaalpabet>
q
</thelettersofdaalpabet>
</xml>
<messages>
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: main.thelettersofdaalpabet() is applicable for argument types: (main$_run_closure2$_closure4) values: [main$_run_closure2$_closure4@ba47ffaf]
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: main.thelettersofdaalpabet() is applicable for argument types: (main$_run_closure2$_closure4) values: [main$_run_closure2$_closure4@ba47ffaf]
    at main$_run_closure2.doCall(main.groovy:10)
    at coercionbuilder$_closure1.doCall(coercionbuilder.groovy:7)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.methodMissing(Unknown Source)
    at builderrules$methodMissing.call(Unknown Source)
    at coercionbuilder.propertyMissing(coercionbuilder.groovy:14)
    at coercionbuilder.setProperty(coercionbuilder.groovy)
    at main.run(main.groovy:9)
```

when the map is coerced into GroovyObject it outputs:

```
<xml>
<thelettersofdaalpabet>
q
</thelettersofdaalpabet>
</xml>
Caught: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.invokeMethod(Unknown Source)
    at coercionbuilder.propertyMissing(coercionbuilder.groovy:14)
    at coercionbuilder.setProperty(coercionbuilder.groovy)
    at main.run(main.groovy:9)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just shooting from the hip here, but have you tried setting the closure resolve strategy to DELEGATE_FIRST:

```
...
                for (Closure c : args) {
                    c.delegate = b
                    c.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
                    def out = c()
                    if (out != null) println out
                }
...
```

?